# Wordpress Live Broadcast Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I make a live broadcast site in Wordpress. But I couldn't use the live streaming plugin. I can only broadcast with WpStream. Can you help me?

Comment: We need some more basic information. What version of wordpress are you using? What is "the live streaming plugin" that you refer to?

Comment: As written, unfortunately there's not enough information to go on (and I'm unsure whether this is a programming question). Perhaps this question would be better at wordpress.stackexchange.com...